# How to store custom objects in a vector for storage during the life of a server in c++

Tags: c++, vector, storage, temporary

I am coming from a Java background and so am used to moving objects around directly, but I am having trouble doing so in c++. Basically I have a `message` object that I create in a loop. In that loop I pass the `message` object into a function to be edited and have its values set. I then return the object back to the loop. After editing the object I want to save it in a vector that is stored in the same class as this loop it is running in.

The problem I am facing is that after running the loop a couple of times, say three, I expect that I should be able to access the vector and have 3 separate objects with unique values, as the loop should have made a new one each time, but instead I find that all the elements contain the same info as the most recently stored object.

I am guessing it has to do with pointers and reference use. I have searched stack overflow for similar questions but nothing has helped so far. Here are some code pieces:

Creating the message:

```
void Server::handle(int client) {
    //cout << "CONNECTED! :)\n";
    while (1) {
        string request = "";
        Message message;
        message.needed = false;
        request = get_request(client);
        if (request.empty()){break;}
         message = parse_request(request, message);
        //cout << "Parsed request." << "\n";
        if (message.needed){
            get_value(client, message);
        }
        handle_message(client, message);
    }
    close(client);
}
```

Editing it:

```
Message Server::parse_request(string request, Message message) {
    //cout << "Parsing: " << request << "\n";
    //Message message; // = new Message();
    istringstream iss(request);
    iss >> message.command; //store the command
    if(message.command=="put")  {
        //cout << "put\n";
        iss >> message.params[0]; //store user name
        iss >> message.params[1]; //store subject name
       ....etc
    }
    return message;
}
```

Finally storing it:

```
bool Server::handle_message(int client, Message message){
    if(message.command=="put"){
        int count = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<messages.size(); i++){
            if(messages[i].params[0] == message.params[0]){
                count++;
            }
            cout << "Message: " << message.params[1] << "\n";
        }
        message.params[3] = count;
        cout << "Stored a message for: " << message.params[0] << " with " << message.params[2] << " bytes\n";
        messages.push_back(message);
        send_response(client,"OK\n");
    }   
}
```

Here is the .h:

```
class Message {
    public: 
        Message();
        ~Message(); 
        string command;
        string params[4];
        string value;
        bool needed;

    private:
        bool copy(Message message);
};

class Server {
    public:
        Server(int port, bool debugging);
        ~Server();

        void run();

    private:
        void create();
        void close_socket();
        void serve();
        void handle(int);
        string get_request(int);
        bool send_response(int, string);
        Message parse_request(string, Message);
        void get_value(int, Message);
        bool handle_message(int,Message);

        int port_;
        int server_;
        int buflen_;
        char* buf_; 
        string requestcache;
        string valuecache;
        bool debug_;
        vector<Message> messages;
};
```

Comment: If you don't want copies of `Message` you better use a `std::unique_ptr<Message>` to store in the vector.

Comment: Where is your `std::vector` ? Please show relevant parts of declaration of ̀`Message`, so **edit your question** please

Comment: Just for clarification: The `messages.push_back(message)`part will create a copy of the `message` object stored int the `messages` object. If your data is incorrect, I'm assuming the `Message` copy c'tor has a failure.

Comment: Whenever you're declaring a parameter/return type to be a plain `string` or `Message`, you're making a __copy__ of it. Prefer passing things by __(const) reference__ (`(const) &`) when you don't intend to pass a copy.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. I had to create a new pointer object that I would then copy all the values from the message object from and store that instead. Also, I realized I had a logic error where I was referencing the "message" object instead of the "messages" object. After these fixes, the code was running! :) thanks for the help guys, biggest help to m*mble for getting me to think about a few spots more.

Comment: Idiomatic way is properly define copy constructor.